# How to "speed up" basic investment formula?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have [a formula](http://www.moneychimp.com/articles/finworks/fmbasinv.htm) (start of year, not end) for calculating basic investment, but it only works when calculated once per year. Say I wanted to add interest every day so that after a year the total be the same as the above formula pays out once a year. How would I adjust the formula to do that?

Comment: Is the formula in that link?  If so please enter it here using MathJax.  I don't follow links out of the site.  One question will be to do with rounding.  An answer calculated by a computer would be subject to intermediate rounding.

Comment: idk how to use MathJax but the formula is `Balance(Y)   =   P(1 + r)^Y + c[((1 + r)^(Y + 1) - (1 + r)) / r]`. The link explained the formula in depth so I thought it better to post that.

Comment: There is a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference. And plenty more on the web if you search.  People here will be much more willing to help if you learn to format your answers nicely.

Comment: It sounds as if your question may be more about programming than maths. If so, this is not the best site.

Comment: Well it is being used for programming but that's irrelevant to what I need, which is just a math formula.

Comment: If I go to stackoverflow asking for help with a math formula they'll just point me here lol

Comment: You say below "I'd have to store extra variables" - that sounds like programming not maths.  Another tricky point is rounding.  A maths answer will deal with exact calculations. A computer will deal with approximations.  A mathematician may give you a clever formula that will do the same job more efficiently. When you run it on a real computer, you might get slightly different results. Would that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you would do is get the percentage and round it and turn it from a percentage to a number. After that, you're going to get that number and add it to the actual calculation or the result. You would adjust the calculation and divide it to the actual interest of the percentage. Afterwards, you would be left with a percentage which is the result of dividing the first division to the actual result without interest, you would keep that result somewhere and redo the whole process while using the **NEW** result.

Comment: Doesn't work like that, formula isn't that simple. And even if it did I'd have to store extra variables to do it, which is also a no go.